# how to find out if a function with binary variable is linear or not?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I have a function R with a binary variable y_{iF} as follows:

[image]

Other things like D_{iF}, P, X are parameters.

My question is that how can I find out if function R is linear or not? Is there any usual way to find out it?

Comment: If R only depends on parameters (i.e. constants) then R is constant also. So the question about linearity is moot.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen. I know that you told, it is obvious! If you read my question exactly, I told that there is a binary deciecion variable y, which is included in D, and D is included in R.

Comment: " D, P, X are parameters". Optimization problems have decision variables and parameters (aka coefficients or constants)..As R only depends on D and X it is also constant. I am glad you find this obvious.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I meant D_{iF} is parameter but D_{i} depends on binary decision variable y_{iF} and so R depends on y_{iF}.